# Formula on List Price for specific products

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

How can I use a formula to calculate list price based on custom fields for certain products? I though I could I set the list price at 0 since it's required then create a process builder to update the field based on the fields that are filled out on the product line, but that doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you want to update the List Price for a Product based on values on a custom field from Process Builder and that you are not able to do so? Do you have a custom price book where you have this Product mapped to?

Comment: On Opportunity Product I added the custom fields that are needed to calculate the list price. Since this "pricing calculator" only applies to certain products, I was thinking I would have to set the list price at 0 (since list price is required), then create a process builder that says when X product is added to an opp, use the formula to update list price. I'm not sure if this is the right or best way, but this is what I need to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List Price is always associated to a Custom Pricebook. You are only able to add a List Price within that Pricebook. Refer to the below from [Considerations for Setting Prices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=products_considerations_for_setting_prices.htm&type=5) documentation:

> A ***list price*** is the custom price that you associate with a product in a custom price book. For example, you can maintain one set of prices for domestic orders and another for international orders.

So, in order for you to update the List Price whenever you are adding an Opportunity Product, you have to basically update the List Price on the Pricebook Entry associated with that Product.

With a quick test, the following Process Builder works fine. You will need to create a Process Builder on Opportunity Product and choose the associated Pricebook Entry's List Price to be updated. You can adjust the formula based on your custom fields here.

[image]

---

While this works, I will not recommend to use this approach though. List Price are associated with a Price book. So wherever that Price book will be used, changes with this approach will have an impact on all such Opportunity Products associated to different Opportunities wherever the Price book is referenced. Instead you should create another field on the Opportunity Product and use that for your use case.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now is there a way to revert it back to 0 when it's used the next time? This list price formula is different every time it is sold as it is dependent on changing variables per sale. It comes up with the previous calculation price the next time I select it.

Comment: You will need to redo the same approach every time you want to update the List Price. To be honest, I will not recommend setting up the List Price every time whenever you are adding an Opportunity Product. List Price are associated with Price books, and that wherever that Price book will be used, the List Price will be impacted. Instead you should create another field on the Opportunity Product and use that for your use case.